# php list of update queries only some working no errors

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using a list of Insert and Update queries to process the turns for my strategy game. Here are some that worked and others that didn't.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE gc3025_games_prime SET `turns` = `turns`+1 WHERE `active`='1'");
mysql_query("UPDATE gc3025_processing_check, gc3025_games_prime SET gc3025_processing_check.turn = gc3025_games_prime.turns WHERE gc3025_processing_check.game_id = gc3025_games_prime.id");
mysql_query("UPDATE gc3025_processing_check SET `turn_update`='yes' WHERE `game_id`='1' AND `turn`='$current_turn'");
```

These are right after and didn't process. They do process when I manually enter them on the server.

```
mysql_query ("UPDATE `gc3025_cbills_remaining` SET `cbills_remaining` = `unspent_cbills`");
mysql_query ("UPDATE `gc3025_cbills_remaining` SET `starting_cbills` = `cbills_remaining` + `base_cbills`");
mysql_query ("UPDATE `gc3025_cbills_remaining` SET `unspent_cbills` = starting_cbills");
```

Is there a way to make sure they actually process? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: remove '' from table_name `gc3025_cbills_remaining`

Comment: @AtifTariq - er, no. The table name in the last three queries is correctly quoted with backticks.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`mysql_affected_rows`](http://php.net/manual/it/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) to obtain what you need.

You can obtain two different values from this call

- `-1` (tells you that something didn't worked)
- ***integer value*** `>= 0` (tells you the exact number of row affected)

BTW I would suggest not to use `mysql_*` functions: use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)